# Calculating Euclidean Distance for Large DataSets

Tags: r, distance

I have to calculate Euclidean distance between train and test data. the total length of train data is 1389 and for test data is 364. It is basically the data from the handwritten ZIP codes on envelopes from U.S. postal mail, downloaded from the [website](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) of "Elements of Statistical learning".

I am a beginner and just read the data in R package.  I'm unable to start calculating distance between train and test data. Can anyone help me out to give me an idea that how to generate a loop for this data?

I would be thankful.

Comment: This question is quite vague in its current form, but after you read your data in, look at the `?dist` function...it will calculate your Euclidean distance for you

Comment: Thanks for your help. I explored and learned about the library (fields). Actually I have to perform KNN  (supervised classiication)on the given dataset and I am following the methodology of Calculate distances, Sort, select neighbors,and then predict. I have K values 1,3,5,7,& 15. if my question is understandable then can you explain a bit?

Answer (score 6):

For Euclidian distances, I like using `rdist` from the `fields` packages. One advantage over `dist` from the `stats` package, is that it can take two matrices as input:

```
train.data <- matrix(runif(1389*2), ncol = 2)
test.data  <- matrix(runif(364*2),  ncol = 2)

library(fields)
distances <- rdist(train.data, test.data)
dim(distances)
# [1] 1389  364
```