# Howto calculate distance between two groups of data

Tags: r, dataframe, distance

I've got 2 data frames - learn data with L rows and test data with T rows.

I want to compute a L*T matrix with distances (euclidean, manhattan, cosine...) between according elements.

Here is my take:

```
distance2 <- function (x1, x2) {
            temp <- x1 - x2
            sum(temp * temp)
}

m <- matrix(0,nrow(learnData),nrow(testData))
for(td in 1:nrow(testData)) {
    for(ld in 1:nrow(learnData)) {
        m[ld,td] <- distance2(testData[td,],learnData[ld,])                 
    }
}
```

I think this can be done in a more compact, "R" way. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: For euclidean, you better use `rdist` from the `fields` package. It is faster than `dist` and more adapted to your requirements (two data frames). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10220868/1201032

Comment: Thanks, I tried and it works exactly as I want. I chose proxy package which does the same thing, but has lots of different measures already implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options spring to mind:

1. Use the **proxy** package which has many of these dissimilarity coefficients already coded and can compute this for two data frames separately
2. The **analogue** package, which has function `distance()` which can compute the Euclidean and Manhattan measures for you on two data frames (but not the cosine distance).

Comment: Proxy package is great, really lots of distances and similarity measures. And it does what I want, thanks.